# Change DataGrid cell value in VB6

Tags: datagrid, vb6

Good day guys.
I am developing VB6 project and I know it's old but thats the standard in Japan. I am not into datagrid expert guy that can tweak everything inside of it but my problem is that I have data to be displayed in datagridview which they want to change the cell value if the data having value for example :

### FRUIT | QTY

apple       | 1

orange     | 2

So if apple having QTY value of "1" I want to change it into something like star or circle value.

It's a datagrid control(databound) in WinForm App. My datasource is sql server.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Are you talking DataGrid Control (in .NET) or Excel Worksheet cell? Thanks and regards,

Comment: @AlexBell datagrid control sorry I forgot to include it. Thank you

Comment: Is it ASP or WinForm app?

Comment: WinForm app mate. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology (VB6) is indeed very old; you can try something like

```
Sub AddSymbol()
For i = 1 To DataGrid1.Rows
    If DataGrid1.Item(i, 2) = 1 Then DataGrid1.Item(i, 2) = "*"
Next i
End Sub
```

where quantity is stored in the second column of `DataGrid1` control. Hope this may help.

Comment: How about checking the length of string so that I can change everything having values not only 1? Can I populate it using your code? Can't even test my laptop is broken. I can only test in my office. Gonna post feedback tommorrow. Thanks mate 

Comment: I've answered your original question: please mark it accepted if satisfied. In case your could have more questions, please post them separately. Thanks and regards,

Comment: DataGrid1.Rows-> DataGrid1.Row
DataGrid1.Item(i, 2)-> no item method available in datagrid